# how to skip the NEXT for iteration?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When trying to scrape a website that has promotional price and regular price both of these elements are found by selenium webdriver. i want to: if the promotional price is found, skip the next iteration, which would be the regular price. "price price-final" being the promotional price and "price price-from" being the regular price.

`

```
        remedios= driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price-number")
        
        for element in remedios:
            try:
                driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price price-final")
                preco=(element.text).replace("R$","").replace(",",".")
                listaremedio=[{'preco':preco,'farmacia':farmacia}]
                listabraba.extend(listaremedio)
            except:
                try:
                    driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price price-from")
                    preco=(element.text).replace("R$","").replace(",",".")
                    listaremedio=[{'preco':preco,'farmacia':farmacia}]
                    listabraba.extend(listaremedio)   
                except:
                    pass
```

`
this is the code im using. it works "right", it does get the promotional price if its avaiable. but as the next element in "remedios" is going to be the regular price, it also gets that. i want something that makes it basically: if this iteration had a promotional price, skip the next iteration. that would make it go to the next card, skipping the regular price. thanks for the attention. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an inner for loop here:

```py
remedios= driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price-number")

for element in remedios:
    for name in ('price price-final', 'price price-from'):
        try:
            driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, name)
        except:
            # element not found
            continue
        else:
            break
    else: # if no break statement was encountered, no elements found
        continue

    preco = element.text.replace("R$","").replace(",",".")
    listaremedio = [{'preco': preco, 'farmacia': farmacia}]
    listabraba.extend(listaremedio)
```

Comment: with that code we still get both prices, for instance in https://www.drogasil.com.br/medicamentos/medicamentos/todos-de-a-z.html?p=1 . we get 10.59 AND 8.39. i would like it to get only the 8.39 then the 3.23 from the next card, the 156.50 from the next and so on. and get the regular price only if theres no promotional price. does that make sense?

Comment: It *shouldn't* get both. It's short-circuiting, just like yours does. If there's a `price-final`, a `break` should happen and that gets added to your list. If there isn't the `except` fires, which skips to `price-from`. If there's a `price-from`, then it finds that

Comment: Note that you aren't doing anything with the result of `driver.find_elements` in the for loop